# Position of GCC stack canaries

Tags: gcc, x86, buffer-overflow, stack-memory, ida

Unless I am misunderstanding something, it seems the position of the canary value can be before or after `ebp`, therefore in the second case the attacker can overwrite the frame pointer without touching the canary.

For example in this snippet, the canary is located at a lower address (`ebp-0xc`) than `ebp` therefore protecting it (an attacker must overwrite the canary to overwrite `ebp`):

```
0x080484e0 <+52>: mov eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
0x080484e3 <+55>: xor eax,DWORD PTR gs:0x14
0x080484ea <+62>: je 0x80484f1 <func+69>
0x080484ec <+64>: call 0x8048360 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
```

However looking at other code the canary is after `rbp+8`:

[image: screenshot]

How should I interpret this? Does this depend on GCC version or something else?

Comment: Where did you get the second piece of code?  Every gcc version I tried on godbolt puts the canary below the frame pointer.  https://godbolt.org/z/hrPere1vr

Comment: From here : https://ret2rop.blogspot.com/2020/05/canary-pie-byte-bruteforce.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canary is always below the frame pointer, with every version of gcc I've tried.  You can see that confirmed in the gdb disassembly immediately below the IDA disassembly in the blog post you linked, which has `mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]`.

I think this is just an artifact of IDA's disassembler.  Instead of displaying the numerical offset for `rbp`-relative addresses, it assigns a name to each stack slot, and displays the name instead; basically assuming that every `rbp`-relative access is to a local variable or argument.  And it looks like it always displays that name with a `+` regardless of whether the offset is positive or negative.  Note that `buf` and `fd` also get a `+` sign even though they are local variables which are clearly below the frame pointer.

In this example, it has named the canary `var_8` as if it were a local variable.  So I suppose to translate this properly, you have to think of `var_8` as having the value `-8`.

Comment: Thanks that could explain it, I never used IDA so i'm not familiar with its convention and assumed the "+" is a literral "+".

Comment: @AaaBbb `+` *is* a literal `+`. The point is that `var_8` is `-8`. Yeah, it's annoying, you'll get used to it. This is IDA's convention for stack variables.